# reference for soliton solutions

Tags: nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis, soliton-theory

I have written 3 nonlinear, coupled equations to describe a system. I have heard about soliton solutions for nonlinear equations, but I don't know anything about them. Could anyone introduce a good reference for someone who doesn't know anything about soliton solutions of nonlinear equations? I have searched before but results were not good for someone who wants to now simply about them.
I'm a physics student and I don't want to read an expert book on mathematics. I just want to understand the concept and how to use it if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the book  [P. G. Drazin: Solitons: An Introduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521336554). It offers a nice introduction to the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider looking into Alex Kasman's [Glimpses of Soliton Theory](https://bookstore.ams.org/stml-54) which while perhaps more mathematically inclined than Drazin's still is quite accessible.